# Python Script not working as expected when run by Crontab

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, cron

I have to run a specific python script which is requesting some data over the REST API every night at 3.
For that I have enabled a crontab:

```sh
0 3 * * * python3 /home/pi/path/to/script.py >> /home/pi/logfile.txt 2>&1
```

When I execute the script on its own everything is working as expected, but when the cron starts the script I get errors that the nameserver can not resolve my request:

```sh
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 748, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I verified that the script is executed by the same user (pi).

Im behind a company proxy but so far I had no problems with that when launching it manually. Can someone point me to the difference in the execution. I thougt it has to be the same.

- Hardware: Pi4 4GB
- OS: Linux raspi 5.10.11-v7l+ #1399 SMP Thu Jan 28 12:09:48 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
- Software:

  - Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) [GCC 8.3.0] on linux
  - requests==2.21.0

UPDATE:

I found out that the problem is that the global proxy settings are not active when launching my script with the crontab.

I could make it work when i call a bash script from cron that is setting the proxy and than calling the script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
export http_proxy="http://proxyip:proxyport"
export https_proxy="http://proxyip:proxyport"
python3 /home/pi/path/to/script.py >> /home/pi/logfile.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: can you add a log line showing the Host the script is trying to call ?

Comment: where's the host information coming from ? Is it hardcoded or getting it from a file ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "host information" exactly. But the adress where I sent my REST request is hardcoded in the py script. Can you maybe clarify this for me? Thanks!

Comment: requests is complaining that it can't reach the Host address, but the exception does not show how that looks like.
It would help debugging to have a log line showing that, so you can confirm if it is a permission issue or not.

Comment: Thanks for your input so far it seems you are on the right track. I found out that when the script is executed by the crontab my global proxy settings in ```/etc/profile.d/proxy.sh``` seems to be not active and that is the reason for the request to fail. Do you may have an idea why that is the case? As mentioned the script is executed in both cases by the user Pi with the uid 1000

Comment: can you try to wrap it in a script, running /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh first and then your python code ?

Comment: had the same idea and this is working fine

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the update above the problem was the proxy. The global settings that are known by pyton when manually executed are not known when launching it from crontab. The solution for this problem is to add the proxy config to the crontab file:

```sh
HTTP_PROXY=http://proxyip:proxyport
HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxyip:proxyport
0 3 * * * python3 /home/pi/path/to/script.py >> /home/pi/logfile.txt 2>&1
```

BUT: This only seems to work within the file directly called form crontab. In my case I call another bash script from the python file that is also not able to resolve the address. For that another call of:

```sh
export http_proxy="http://proxyip:proxyport"
export https_proxy="http://proxyip:proxyport"
```

is needed before execution!

Thanks to *farbiondrive* for giving the hint for the solution!